# Animating canvas shape to center from any position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I am a bit confused on how I can make a shape animate to the center of a canvas. I can get the center value:

```
width = canvas.width = window.innerWidth,
height = canvas.height = window.innerHeight,
centerX = width / 2,
centerY = height / 2;
```

and a simple decrement or increment depending on whether the initial position is positive or negative can be done as well:

```
var x = 100;
var y = 100;

    function fn (){
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.arc(x, y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
       ctx.fillStyle = '#444';
       ctx.fill();
       ctx.closePath();

       x -= 1;
       y -= 1;
    }
```

The animation would be done using:

```
requestAnimationFrame(fn)
```

Problem with all this is. I need to manually adjust the x and y everytime. How can I better simply make the x and y values random for the shape and make it animate to the center, no matter from what direction and if the initial position is negative or positive.  I was thinking of atang2 but honestly im not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically on the right track. Use `Math.sqrt` for the distance and `Math.atan2` to find the direction. Then its just the matter of how fast (velocity) you want the object to move to the target (centre of the canvas).

```
var tx = centerX - x,
    tx = centerY - y,
    distance = Math.sqrt(tx * tx + ty * ty),
    radius = Math.atan2(ty, tx),
    angle = (radius / Math.PI) * 180;

// Ensure we don't divide by zero if distance is 0
if (distance !== 0)
{
   velX = (tx / distance) * velocity;
   velY = (ty / distance) * velocity;

   x += velX;
   y += velY;
}
```

Comment: I have a new jsfiddle. Am I on the right track there too? http://jsfiddle.net/4zmnrwzj/2/

Comment: I see, I never used sqrt before and always wondered why to use it at all

Comment: I could need some assistance understanding how the distance part works. For example why multiplying tx by tx etc.

Comment: We're basically using Pythagoras rule here to calculate the distance between 2 points. https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/distance-2-points.html

Comment: wow thank you so much. I am going to read all of this. Math is definately worth it now.

Comment: In a matter of fact it helps. I just implemented your code and it worked fine, but yours is much cleaner. What I was wondering and couldnt figure out is why the ball only animates from the bottom right side. I think because math random only gives numbers between 0 and canvas size. I could fix this by adding a negative minimum. Thanks for your answer and especially the link to that math site!

Comment: That works -- upvote. :-) BTW, mathematically simpler is `closerX=originalX+(originalX-centerX)*pct` where pct is the desired percentage of the way between originalX and centerX (0<=pct<=1.00)...and same for closerY.

Comment: Just a quick warning on the answer. There is a strong possibility that the solution will crash when the center is reached. In this case the solution is normalising the vector tx,ty towards the center (normalize is making a vector one unit long)  If the distance to the center is zero you will get a divide by zero error that will halt your code.. When normalising a vector alway check that you are not dividing by zero.

Comment: This was just a proof of concept Blindman but admittedly you are correct. I've amended the response.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given is flawed as there is no check for divide by zero. This error can easily be overlooked and then crop up in production code making it very hard to find out what has gone wrong.

Should be

```
var tx = centre.x - x;
var ty = centre.y - y;
var dist = Math.sqrt(tx * tx + ty * ty);
// or 
var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tx, 2) + Math.pow(ty, 2));
if(dist !== 0){ // must have this test or when the coords get to the centre 
                // you will get a divide by zero
     tx /= dist;  // Normalise direction vector
     ty /= dist;
}
tx *= speed; // set the magnitude to required speed;
ty *= speed; // Note that if at the centre this will be zero
x += tx;
y += ty;
```